# How to pass settings to Nservicebus JsonSerializer in C#?

Tags: c#, nservicebus, jsonserializer

Based on https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/serialization/json, I would like to pass some settings to the JsonSerializer, such as IgnoreNullValues for example.
But so far I didn't find out any example of how to pass settings to the serializer.

```
var serialization = endpointConfiguration.UseSerialization<JsonSerializer>();

//I would like to use something like below, 
//but I don't find any examples of how to pass settings to the JsonSerializer
serialization.Settings.IgnoreNUllValues = true;
```

What I cannot find out is the correct syntax for passing the settings or a list of available settings for the default JsonSerializer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From David Boike comment, this is exactly the answer to my question:

By default JSON.NET is internalized into NServiceBus, which means you **can't set any options** on it or really access its APIs at all. That's why the NewtonsoftSerializer exists, to allow you to use an external JSON.NET package that's in your project with whatever settings you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

As per their [documentation](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/serialization/newtonsoft):

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
    Converters =
    {
        new IsoDateTimeConverter
        {
            DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind
        }
    }
};
var serialization = endpointConfiguration.UseSerialization<NewtonsoftSerializer>();
serialization.Settings(settings);
```

This does use the NewtonsoftSerializer, instead of the JsonSerializer so your mileage may vary.

Comment: I've seen this solution, but it is using [NewtonsoftSerializer](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/serialization/newtonsoft) which is a separate package. I was trying to use the [JsonSerializer](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/serialization/json) which comes by default with nsb. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @znn By default JSON.NET is internalized into NServiceBus, which means you can't set any options on it or really access its APIs at all. That's why the NewtonsoftSerializer exists, to allow you to use an external JSON.NET package that's in your project with whatever settings you'd like.